# Perdiodical data fetch should block other threads using a schedueler

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduler, apscheduler

I am kind of a newbie in python. I am appreciate for any help. So let's get started.

I am running a FLASK apllication as a rest api. With every request, a json is given back. There might be about 20 Requests per second. In the background, i am using the APscheduler to fetch actual data every 60 seconds from ldap.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(
    func=my_ldap.fetch_people_ldap,
    trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=60),
    id='fetching_data_job',
    name='Fetch data from ldap every 60 seconds')

scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda : scheduler.shutdown())
```

But actually, when hit the datafetch with an api call, the application is shutting down cause of a memory issue, i think it is cause of i access the ldap object at the same time the `fetch_people_ldap`- function is calles by the scheduler.

I want to solve this horrible bug by blocking the thread which handle the api calls until the ldap data fetch was exited sucessfully. But i don't know how to do this.

Are there any recommendations or soulutions?

This is the log i get for the error:
Fatal Python error: saving thread twice?

```
Thread 0x00007f95f3fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 294 in _ldap_call
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 721 in result4
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 714 in result3
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 707 in result2
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 703 in result
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 796 in search_ext_s
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 802 in search_s
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 49 in fetch_people_ldap
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125 in run_job
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 66 in _worker
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f95f8910700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 297 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 549 in wait
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/blocking.py", line 28 in _main_loop
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007f9605505700 (most recent call first):
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 294 in _ldap_call
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 791 in search_ext
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 795 in search_ext_s
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 802 in search_s
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 59 in check_node
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 118 in build_tree_recursive
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 124 in build_tree_recursive
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 124 in build_tree_recursive
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 129 in build_tree
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/app/app.py", line 83 in get_trainings_by_unit
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598 in dispatch_request
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982 in wsgi_app
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997 in __call__
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 197 in execute
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209 in run_wsgi
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 267 in handle_one_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422 in handle
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 232 in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 341 in process_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 313 in _handle_request_noblock
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 234 in serve_forever
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 539 in serve_forever
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 702 in inner
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 739 in run_simple
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841 in run
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/app/app.py", line 92 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your API call handler is also calling out to LDAP to create the response. If you're going to get 20 requests per second then that's going to cause problems. The scheduled call also doesn't make much sense because when are you using the data you retrieved?

My approach would be to have the scheduled task update a common data store in the background. Then your API call only reads the data from that common data store and does not have to touch LDAP at all. Whether you use a database or just memory depends on the size and complexity of the data you're working with.

The main thing is to decouple creating the API response from fetching the data from LDAP.

**EDIT:**
I understand from your comment that you think your API is only using your own ldapCheck.py code, but if you look at the full stack trace, it is actually using the LDAP library to make a call:

API Thread:

```
Current thread 0x00007f9605505700 (most recent call first):
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 294 in _ldap_call
...
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 124 in build_tree_recursive
...
File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/app/app.py", line 83 in get_trainings_by_unit
...
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841 in run
```

When this happens at the same time as your scheduled background thread is making a call to LDAP, you get this error.

```
Thread 0x00007f95f3fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/path/to/folder/virtual_env_1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyldap-2.4.37-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 294 in _ldap_call
...
  File "/path/to/folder/tt_report_api/training_tool_report_api/sample/ldap_check/ldapCheck.py", line 49 in fetch_people_ldap
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap
```

The solution is not to block your API thread. The solution is to make sure the code in `ldapCheck.py", line 59 in check_node` does not make a call to your LDAP library, but uses the information already retrieved and stored by the background thread.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for your response. I think the appproach you described is the one that i used in my tool. I've a local ldap object and fetching the data again after the interval, to keep the data up to date. Since i use the Apscheduler, the problem is that the fuction which use the ldap object and the scheduler want to access the data the same time, cause they running in serveral threads. Is there a way to pause the main thread while the child thread fetch the data from ldap ?